# Clownfishes and Sea anemones

Tags: zoology, ichthyology

Relation between clownfishes and sea anemones is a classic example of mutualism. I wanted to list the species of sea anemones that are involved in this mutualism but I got lost.. Could you help me with that?

How many species of sea anemones which host clownfishes are there? Could you list them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only found this two references, but these are only secondary sources at the moment.
Look here "[Clown Fish Anemone](http://animal-world.com/Aquarium-Coral-Reefs/Clown-Fish-Anemones)" and here "[Choosing Clownfish and Anemones for Your Aquarium](http://animal-world.com/Aquarium-Coral-Reefs/Clown-Fish-Anemones)". It seems that there are only around two handful of anemones capable of supporting clownfish. 
Here are some primary sources which confirm the 10 anemone species: "[The anemonefish symbiosis: What is known and what is not](http://www.nhm.ku.edu/inverts/pdf/Fautin_anemonefishsymbiosis_1991.pdf)." and "[Field guide to anemonefishes and their host sea anemones](http://eqzotica.ucoz.ru/_ld/0/9_ANEMONES.pdf)". The last two links point to PDFs which contain a lot more references.